# FFMPEG Encode encode into .3g2 best quality?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'd like to get the best .3g2 quality for my video encoding. I've read about this format on wiki, but as a newbie, I'm not sure to get the best sound/video bitrate.
Format sizes are 128x96, 176x144, 352x288, 704x576, and max 1408x1152 pixels.
I couldn't find the highest video bitrate.
I've tried this :

ffmpeg -i C:\projet.avi -s 1408x1152 -vf "split [a], pad=iw*2:ih [b], [a] alphaextract, [b] overlay=w" -vb 1220000000 -ac 1 -ar  8000 C:\projet.alpha.3g2

it says
"[h263 @ 0000000000666bc0] bitrate tolerance 4000000 too small for bitrate 12200000000, overriding
[libopencore_amrnb @ 000000000066aee0] bitrate not supported: use one of 4.75k, 5.15k, 5.90k, 6.70k, 7.40k, 7.95k, 10.20k, 12.20k, using 12.20k"
I don't understand what it means ?

Others : I've tried to mention stereo sound, 44000Hz, but it seems not supported.
Any help/Suggestions ? Thank you !

P.S: I need alpha channel and .3g2 for an Augmented Reality software on iOS and Android.

LAST EDIT : I'm still with
ffmpeg -i c:/test.avi -s 1408x1152 -vf "split [a], pad=iw*2:ih [b], [a] alphaextract, [b] overlay=w" -vb 4000000 -ac 1 -ar 8000 C:\test.alpha.3g2
It's working well except error messages, and bad quality sound. Any more ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

For video, your supplied bitrate (`1200M`!) is too high. Use `-q:v 1` instead of `-b:v` for best quality.

For audio, by default, ffmpeg tells the encoder to use a bitrate of 128k unless specified otherwise. Which is not valid for the default encoder used here. So the encoder has overridden the generic value with `12.20k`.

---

If your application supports it, use

```
ffmpeg -i C:\projet.avi -filter_complex "[0]alphaextract[a];[0][a]hstack" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a aac C:\projet.alpha.3g2
```

Comment: ffmpeg -i C:\test.avi -filter_complex "[0]alphaextract[a];[0][a]hstack" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a aac C:\test.alpha.3g2

Video encoded is not valid with AR software.
ffmpeg said : 
"No pixel format specified, yuv444p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players."

Comment: I tried :
ffmpeg -i C:\test.avi -vf "split [a], pad=iw*2:ih [b], [a] alphaextract, [b] overlay=w" -q:v 1 -ac 1 -ar  8000 C:\test.alpha.3g2

And plenty of this 
"[h263 @ 0000000000eb7480] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127its/s speed=0.749x
Last message repeated 462 times"

I usually have some of this message when I put bitrate 12200000000, but not that much.

Comment: For the first command, insert `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. You can ignore the 2nd command messages. H.263 is an older codec and compresses more aggressively.

Comment: I've tried 
ffmpeg -i C:\projet.avi -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter_complex "[0]alphaextract[a];[0][a]hstack" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a aac C:\projet.alpha.3g2
It doesn't work with the AR software.
I think you must use only h263.